# Unsupport major.minor class version 52 error

Tags: java, tomcat

It might be duplicate, but I've duplicated the answers and still not yet working.

I have
1. Got this error:

> java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: GetAssocId : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 (unable to load class GetAssocId)

2. Set my JAVA_HOME to

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91

3.Set my PATH to

> C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;c:\scripts;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\xampp\php;C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin; C:\instantclient_12_1;C:\Python27;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin;

4.Restarted the server

5. JVM version still says

> 1.7.0_79-b15

6. Set my JRE_HOME to

> C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121

I understand that 52 code represents to execute the code in JAVA 2 SE 8, but apart from this instructions, have I missed anything?

Comment: Which server you are using?

Comment: XAMPP server, tomcat is 7.0.73

Comment: Well presumably something earlier in your path has java in it... so look through each element of the path you've given to work out where it's loading it from. You might want to try uninstalling Java 1.7...

Comment: `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath` - what is this? Also you can set path to java directly in `setenv.bat` or `catalina.bat`

Comment: Also check if `JRE_HOME` is present in env variables. AFAIK if present it is preferred over `JAVA_HOME`.

Comment: @JonSkeet It indeed did have path to java 1.7, I've just removed it from path and added path to java 1.8. I just thought removing from `Path` will sever their ties.

Comment: You should uninstall old Java installations. Only keep the most recent one.

Comment: Is there any other alternative for Uninstalling 1.7? Because It might actually be useful for some legacy software that I've built. So @Robert, uninstall is probably off the table.